# How do i Permanently disable fn key lock when laptop reboots

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

When laptop reboots, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is automatically on.
How can I disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key when rebooting ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look in the BIOS of your computer.
At startup, spam the <kbd>Del</kbd> key or <kbd>F11</kbd> or maybe another depending on the model (look at the manual) and maybe you will find an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key option somewhere, it's hard to answer without knowing the model.

A link that can help you is [TomsHardware.com](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bios-keys-to-access-your-firmware,5732.html).